# PHP Prepare statement failure

Tags: php, prepared-statement

The Following code will display "12" on the screen. That is all. These echo numbers were added for debugging.

It should Display "123" and insert into a MySQL database the variables in the statement.
For some reason it just ends at the prepare statement. The fail() error check never getting called. Actually, nothing gets called after the prepare statement.

I have been all over the site and believe I am doing everything required properly, but it is more then likely something I did.

Can anyone tell me why the prepare statement is failing this way?

```
$query = "insert into member(mail, user, val) values (?, ?, ?)";
$uuu = blah@blah.com;
$hhh = Blah Williams;
$val = 0;
echo "1";
if($stmt = $this->conn)
{
    echo "2";
    $stmt->prepare($query) || $this->fail('MySQL prepare', $stmt->error);
    echo "3";
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $uuu, $hhh, $val)
        || $this->fail('MySQL bind_param', $stmt->error);
    $stmt->execute();
    if (!$stmt->execute()) 
    {
        if ($stmt->errno === 1062 /* ER_DUP_ENTRY */)
        {
            $this->fail('This username is already taken');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->fail('MySQL execute', $stmt->error);
        }
    }
}
else 
{/*error check*/
    $this->fail('MySQL insert prepare failed', $stmt->error);
    return 0;
}
$stmt->close();
return true;
```

Comment: Make sure you always have php.ini setting enabled to report all level error including fatal errors. It can save lot of your time. or use xdebug like debug extension.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have access to the php.ini file on this server.

Comment: It would be convenient to set up wamp/lamp/mamp for developing and testing locally rather than any 3rd party server. though you can use http://php.net/ini_set to override some of php.ini settings at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use as your assignment will always be true.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
```

To check why it's failing, use:

```
var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
```

Comment: if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query))

Comment: No - you can keep your || $this->fail(..) if you like. Both methods check if it returns true it just depends what logic you want to use to handle that after

Comment: yeah, that was actually the way I had it before all the debugging. Didn't realize it was important.

Comment: if ($stmt = $this->conn) will always be true because you're checking if an assignment was successful

Comment: Ok, so I tried both the if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) and just a stand alone $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query), but it still fails as soon as the prepare is called.

Comment: again it just failed at the prepare statement and never executes the var_dump.

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? it could be throwing an exception if it isn't continuing execution. Check your logs